# How to add a new audio codec driver to linux

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am working with a board named UDOO based on ARM9 processor. I'm using embedded Linux for this board. UDOO company has released the sources of their linux kernel, so I can edit them. Now, we want to design our custom board similar to UDOO board. We noticed that the audio codec of UDOO board is no longer manufactured, so we want to replace it with another one, for example "wm8960" codec. My question is, can anyone tell we what should be the steps to replace the current audio driver with the new one? Knowing that I have already added new drivers to the linux kernel, but it's the first time to handle with audio drivers and I don't know how to make this job.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here.

Comment: A step-by-step guideline in this case would be too broad. If you have faced any specific issue anywhere, let us know.

Comment: You don't need a codec driver (one for the WM9860 already exists), but a machine driver.

Comment: You can write the platform and the machine driver, and include them in the soc folder or snd-soc files in the cross-compiling build you are making.